# SPARK SQL, how expand nested array[.. ] field to flat table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.2.0 and 1.6.1. One of my tasks has following table:

```
|ID|DEVICE     |HASH|
----------------
|12|2,3,0,2,6,4|adf7|
```

where:

- ID - long
- DEVICE - string
- HASH - string

I need to expand field 'DEVICE' to 6 columns, such as:

```
|ID|D1|D2|D3|D4|D5|D6|HASH|
---------------------------
|12|2 |3 |0 |2 |6 |4 |adf7|
```

Thank for help me.

Answer (score 1):

Get the maximum length:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{size, max}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df = Seq(("12", Seq(2, 3, 0, 2, 6, 4), "adf7")).toDF("id", "device", "hash")
val Row(n: Int) = df.select(max(size($"device"))).first
```

If you know the number beforehand just skip this and go straight to the second part.

Once you define `n`, just `select`:

```scala
df.select(
  $"id" +: (0 until n).map(i => $"device"(i).alias(s"d$i")) :+ $"hash": _*
).show

// +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
// | id| d0| d1| d2| d3| d4| d5|hash|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
// | 12|  2|  3|  0|  2|  6|  4|adf7|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Items number of field 'DEVICE' is constant

Comment: Then you can skip the first step.